# General thoughts about one Rest Endpoint and two Consumers

Tags: rest, api, endpoint

Consider the following situation:

- You have one Endpoint, for example ../api/Samples
- All Samples have the Attributes: Name, App.
- You have two Apps which will consume the Samples Endpoint
- The First App (A1) wants all Samples.
- The Second App (A2) wants only a Subset of the Samples. To be exact only the Samples which have 'A2' standing in the 'App' Attribute.

What is the most REST-conform and common sense way to realize this?

So far I thought of three ways:

- Create two Endpoints: ../api/A1Samples and ../api/A2Samples

  > This seems like overhead. What if more Apps come later? The Controller must be duplicated even if most of the code is identical.
- Send the App Type within the URL: ../api/Samples/A1 or A2

  > Would be easier to maintain if more Apps come later. But doesn't this reject the thought of REST?
- Send the App Type within the Accept Header: ../api/Samples and in the Header: App-Type: A1 or A2

  > In my case it seems this isn't easy to implement in ASP.NET Core v1.1 but should be the most syntactically correct way.

Can someone approve or reject my thoughts? Maybe even extend the list or state the usually used solution for this case?

Comment: Note #1: Header parameter should not begin with "X-". It's deprecated, see here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648

Answer (score 0):

If one of the applications requires all samples, it could simply consume /api/Samples directly; for the other one, have an extensible way to specify filters (even if that is just a few GET parameters) - if this is really an "App" attribute that exists on the Sample object then `?App=A2` would make sense, if it is some other attribute then specify those attributes directly.

This is more REST-ful than your `/Samples/A1` and `/Samples/A2` idea because it directly specifies the attribute being queried for (A1 doesn't use `?App=A1` because as you said Application 1 consumes the entire list of sample objects) rather than knowledge of what application is querying it, any similarity is simply due to the (I suspect contrived) structure of the example.

REST isn't just about something as simple as "use path parameters in all cases" - filtering a result list is a clear case for using query parameters instead.